# How to dequeue the default CSS styles on the wp-login.php page?

Tags: login, wp-enqueue-script

I'm loading my own stylesheet on the wp-login.php page using the `login_enqueue_scripts` hook so I have no need for the default styles that come with that page. Is it possible to dequeue styles associated with wp-login.php?

Elsewhere in WordPress, I use `wp_dequeue_style()` to remove a CSS file enqueued with `wp_enqueue_style()`. I'm unsure if the process would be the same for wp-login.php.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, You can use the wp_dequeue_style(), you just have to pass the handler 'login'.

```
function wp_stackexchange_267327() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'login' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_stackexchange_267327' );
```